# Const-correct accessor to vector of pointers without transfer of ownership in abstract interface

Tags: c++, c++14, api-design, c++17

I'm designing a library from scratch and want to get the public API as *good* as possible. I want the compiler to yell at me for misuse. Therefore, I've imposed the following rules on myself:

1. **true (i.e. deep and complete) const correctness throughout the whole library**

   All *things* (local variables, member variables, member functions), which are not expected to change are declared `const`. That constness should propagate to all nested members and types.
2. **explicit and expressive ownership**

   In line with the C++ Core Guidelines I define that as (*iff* in the mathematical sense of *if and only if*):

   1. function arguments are `unique_ptr<T>` or `T&&` *iff* the function is consuming it (i.e. taking ownership)
   2. function arguments are `shared_ptr<const T>` or `T const&` *iff* the function is only reading it
   3. function arguments are `shared_ptr<T>` or `T&` *iff* the function is modifying it without taking ownership
   4. return values are `unique_ptr<T>` or `T` *iff* the function transfers ownership to the caller
   5. return values are `shared_ptr<const T>` or `T const&` *iff* the caller should only read it (though the caller can construct a copy of it - given `T` is copyable)
   6. no functions should return `shared_ptr<T>`, `T&` or `T*` (as it would allow for uncontrollable side effects, which I try to avoid by design)
3. **hidden implementation details**

   For now I'm going with abstract interfaces with factories returning the implementation as a `unique_ptr<Interface>`. Though, I'm open for alternative patterns which solve my problem described below.

I don't care about virtual table lookups and want to avoid dynamic casts by all means (I see them as a code smell).

---

Now, given two classes `A` and `B`, where `B` owns a variable number of `A`s. As well we've the `B`-implementation `BImpl` (implementation of `A` is probably not of use here):

```cpp
class A
{};

class B {
 public:
  virtual ~B() = default;
  virtual void addA(std::unique_ptr<A> aObj) = 0;
  virtual ??? aObjs() const = 0;
};

class BImpl : public B {
 public:
  virtual ~BImpl() = default;
  void addA(std::unique_ptr<A> aObj) override;
  ??? aObjs() const override;

 private:
  std::vector<unique_ptr<A>> aObjs_;
};
```

I'm stuck with the return value of `B`s getter to the vector of `A`s: `aObjs()`.
It should provide the list of `A`s as read-only values without transfer of ownership (rule 2.5. above with const correctness) and still provide the caller easy access to all `A`s, e.g. for use in range-based `for` or standard algorithms such as `std::find`.

I came up with the following options for those `???`:

1. `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const A>> const&`

   I would have to construct a new vector each time I call `aObjs()` (I could cache it in `BImpl`). That feels not only inefficient and needlessly complex, but seems also very suboptimal.
2. Replace `aObjs()` by a pair of functions (`aObjsBegin()` and `aObjsEnd()`) forwarding the constant iterator of `BImpl::aObjs_`.

   Wait. I would need to make that `unique_ptr<A>::const_iterator` a `unique_ptr<const A>::const_iterator` to get my beloved const correctness. Again nasty casts or intermediate objects. And the user couldn't use it easily in range-based `for`.

What obvious solution am I missing?

---

*Edit*:

- `B` should always be able to modify the `A`s it is holding, thus declaring `aObjs_` as `vector<std::unique_ptr<const A>>` is not an option.
- Let `B` adhere to the iterator concept to iterate over the `A`s, is neither an option as `B` will hold a list of `C`s and a specific `D` (or none).

Comment: `std::vector<unique_ptr<const A>> aObjs_;`?

Comment: @TemplateRex If this is too broad, would you be that kind and give me some hints for further research? @HowardHinnant `BImpl` should be able to modify the `A`s it is owning.

Comment: Why can't you just return a const reference to aObjs? I'm very confused.

Comment: Also, a general note: you should never be messing around with shared pointers, if you don't actually need shared ownership. Your other comments make me think that you misunderstand when shared_ptr is appropriate: "function arguments are shared_ptr<const T> or T const& iff the function is only reading it". This is incorrect. You pass by shared_ptr *only* if the function needs to take on shared ownership, if you just need to access T and are not changing its ownership then pass by reference exclusively. Edit: ignore my first comment, I see it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), you may do

```
template <typename T>
using const_view_t = decltype(std::declval<const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>&>() 
                        | ranges::view::transform(&std::unique_ptr<T>::get)
                        | ranges::view::indirect);

class B
{
public:
    virtual ~B() = default;
    virtual void addA(std::unique_ptr<A> a) = 0;    
    virtual const_view_t<A> getAs() const = 0;
};

class D : public B
{
public:
    void addA(std::unique_ptr<A> a) override { v.emplace_back(std::move(a)); }
    const_view_t<A> getAs() const override {
        return v | ranges::view::transform(&std::unique_ptr<A>::get)
                 | ranges::view::indirect;
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> v;
};
```

And then

```
for (const A& a : d.getAs()) {
    std::cout << a.n << std::endl;   
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bfdd5d22dcae6c97)

Comment: That looks smart and would finally give me a reason to finally use range-v3. I'll definitely try that out. At least for the fun of it.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of trying to return the vector directly, you can return a wrapper of a vector that allows you to access the content only with const pointers. It might sound complicated, but it's not. Just make a thin wrapper and add a `begin()` and `end()` function to allow iteration:

```
struct BImpl : B {
    virtual ~BImpl() = default;
    void addA(std::unique_ptr<A> aObj) override;

    ConstPtrVector<A> aObjs() const override {
        return aObjs_;
    }

private:
    std::vector<unique_ptr<A>> aObjs_;
};
```

`ConstPtrVector` will look like this:

```
template<typename T>
ConstPtrVector {
    ConstPtrVector(const std::vector<T>& vec_) : vec{vec_} {}

    MyConstIterator<T> begin() const {
        return vec.begin();
    }

    MyConstIterator<T> end() const {
        return vec.end();
    }

private:
    const std::vector<T>& vec;
};
```

And You can Implement `MyConstIterator` in a way that will return pointers as const:

```
template<typename T>
struct MyConstIterator {
    MyConstIterator(std::vector<unique_ptr<T>>::const_iterator it_) : it{std::move(it_)} {}

    bool operator==(const MyConstIterator& other) const {
        return other.it == it;
    }

    bool operator!=(const MyConstIterator& other) const {
        return other.it != it;
    } 

    const T* operator*() const {
        return it->get();
    }

    const T* operator->() const {
        return it->get();
    }

    MyConstIterator& operator++() {
        ++it;
        return *this;
    }

    MyConstIterator& operator--() {
        --it;
        return *this;
    }

private:
    std::vector<unique_ptr<T>>::const_iterator it;
};
```

Of course, you can generalize this iterator and wrapper by implementing a vector like interface.

Then, to use it, you can use range based for loop or a classic iterator based loop.

BTW: There is nothing wrong with non owning raw pointers. As long as they are still non owning. If you want to avoid error due to raw pointers, look at `observer_ptr<T>`, it might be useful.

Comment: Ok, that's a point I didn't mention in the question: `B` will hold more than just some `A`s. It will also hold some `C`s and a `D`. I might need to completely rethink my model.

Comment: Ok, that different! I'll change this answer to make it work with multiple lists.

Comment: I changed the answer, but I don't tested it with a compiler. If you run into problems with it, just tell me in the comments.

Comment: Why expose the fact that `ConstPtrVector ` wraps a vector?

Comment: I didn't try to find the best name ever. I'm sure OP can figure out what's the best name for his API. This name is in fact quite good for explanation purpose.

Answer (score 3):

```
template<class It>
struct range_view_t {
  It b{};
  It e{};
  range_view_t(It s, It f):b(std::move(s)), e(std::move(f)) {}
  range_view_t()=default;
  range_view_t(range_view_t&&)=default;
  range_view_t(range_view_t const&)=default;
  range_view_t& operator=(range_view_t&&)=default;
  range_view_t& operator=(range_view_t const&)=default;

  It begin() const { return b; }
  It end() const { return e; }
};
```

here we start with a range of iterators.

We can make it richer with `range_view_t remove_front(std::size_t n = 1)const`, `bool empty() const`, `front()` etc.

We can augment it using the usual techniques, conditionally adding `operator[]` and `size` if `It` has a `random_access_iterator_tag` category, and making `remove_front` silently bound `n`.

Then going one step further, we write `array_view_t`:

```
template<class T>
struct array_view_t:range_view<T*> {
  using range_view<T*>::range_view;
  array_view_t()=default; // etc
  array_view_t( T* start, std::size_t length ):array_view_t(start, start+length) {}
  template<class C,
    std::enable_if_t
      std::is_same< std::remove_pointer_t<data_type<C>>, T>{}
      || std::is_same< const std::remove_pointer_t<data_type<C>>, T>{},
      , int
    > =0
  >
  array_view_t( C& c ):array_view_t(c.data(), c.size()) {}
  template<std::size_t N>
  array_view_t( T(&arr)[N] ):array_view_t( arr, N ) {}
};
```

which abstracts looking at the contents of a contiguous container.

Now your `BImpl` returns an `array_view_t< const std::unique_ptr<A> >`.

This level of abstraction is basically free.

---

If that isn't enough, you type erase random access iteration of `T`, then return a `range_view_t< any_random_access_iterator<T> >`, where in this case `T` is `const std::unique_ptr<A>`.

We could also erase the ownership semantics, and just be a `range_view_t< any_random_access_iterator<A*> >` after throwing in a range adapter.

This level of type erasure is not free.

---

For utter insanity, you can stop using smart pointers or interfaces.

Describe your interfaces using type erasure.  Pass out any's wrapped with the type erasure.  Nearly everything uses value semantics.  If you consume a copy, take by value, then move out of that value.  Avoid persistent references to objects.  Short term references are references, or pointers if they are optional.  These are not stored.

Use names instead of addresses, and use a registry somewhere to get at the items, when you cannot afford to use values.

Comment: 1) `It end() const` should return `e`, doesn't it? 2) Are you referring to a specific implementations of `any_random_access_iterator` or just to the concept? 3) Is `data_type` a custom helper template abstracting away e.g. `vector<T>::value_type` and `unique_ptr<T>::elment_type`?

Comment: @torb `template<class T>using data_type=decltype(std::declval<T>().data());`, concept, yes (in reverse order)